# Yosef or Yose? Which is the correct name?

Tags: words, translation, mishna, tractate-chagiga

Why does [Mishnah Chagigah 2](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Chagigah.2.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) say "Yosef" in the translation, rather than "Yose"? Is this a mistake?

For both Yose's, this word, "יוֹסֵי", is used. Why did the translator translate one name as Yose and the other as Yosef, rather than translating both names as Yose or both names as Yosef?

*My knowledge of Hebrew isn't the best, so maybe I'm missing something obvious...(apologies in advance)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version in the printed text of the Gemara ([Chagiga 16a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chagigah.16a.18-16b.1?lang=bi)) has יוסף. The default [translation of the mishna](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Chagigah.2.2?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&lang=en&with=all&lang2=en) on Sefaria is apparently copied from the Koren (William Davidson) translation of the Gemara. (The [Mesorat Hashas](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=13&daf=16&format=pdf) actually changes both of them to יוסף, but the text on Sefaria follows the printed version with one יוסף and one יוסי.)

Comment: Also see the mishna in pirkei avos 1:3 that has the name Yose like the mishna.
https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1?lang=bi